# Add two bands to image gives the bands the same name

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-1, band

I have a sentinel -1 image collection and I have a function that suppose to use focal median in order to apply speckle correction. Each image has 2 bands: VV and VH and the function I have suppose to run this filter on each one and then to add those two bands to the image.

The problem: The added bands don't get the names I chose, as you can see in the following code:

```
var Sentinel1 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
        .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VH'))
        .filter(ee.Filter.eq('orbitProperties_pass', 'DESCENDING'))
        .filter(ee.Filter.eq('instrumentMode', 'IW'))
        .select('VH','VV')
        .filterDate('2020-01-01','2020-01-31')
        .filterBounds(geometry);

var clippedSAR= Sentinel1.map(function(im){ 
  return im.clip(geometry);
}); 

//print(clippedSAR);

var filterSpeckles = function(img) {
  var VH = img.select('VH') ;//select the VH polarization band
  var VV=img.select('VV');
  var VH_smoothed = VH.focal_median(5,'circle','meters').clip(geometry).rename('VH_Filtered'); //Apply a focal median filter
  var VV_smoothed = VV.focal_median(5,'circle','meters').clip(geometry).rename('VH_Filtered'); //Apply a focal median filter
  return img.addBands(VH_smoothed).addBands(VV_smoothed);
};

var Clipped_Speckles = clippedSAR.map(filterSpeckles);
print(Clipped_Speckles);
```

When I print this I get those bands:

[image]

Even though in the code I gave different names to the bands:

```
  return img.addBands(VH_smoothed).addBands(VV_smoothed);
```

why is this happening? how can I be sure it adds the correct bands+ give them the right names?

Comment: Hi Reut. It looks like @Daniel 's answer satisfies your question. Can you please remember to accept answers to remove questions from the list of unanswered questions. It is also a nice way to acknowledge those that have spent time to answer your questions.

Comment: yes ofcurse, I just still haven't gotten to this , i'm greatfuk to Daniel and he helps me a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're adding two bands with the same name, `VH_Filtered`, with the `overwrite` argument set to `false`. It behaves like the documentation states - it renames the band with a numerical suffix.

> **addBands(srcImg, names, overwrite)**
>
> ...
>
> `overwrite (Boolean, default: false)`:
>
> If `true,` bands from srcImg will override bands with the same names in dstImg. Otherwise the new band will be renamed with a numerical
>   suffix ('`foo`' to '`foo_1`' unless '`foo_1`' exists, then '`foo_2`' unless it
>   exists, etc).

Answer (score 0):

You probably copy-pasted the variable declaration without changing rename() part

This

```
var VV_smoothed = V.focal_median(5,'circle','meters').clip(geometry).rename('VH_Filtered');
```

Should be

```
var VV_smoothed = V.focal_median(5,'circle','meters').clip(geometry).rename('VV_Filtered');
```